# how do i block outbound form submitting

Tags: html, forms

I have a profile edit page on my website with preset age and country lists so people can choose their age and country.

My problem is a guy made an HTML form that can submit a custom age and country. Does somebody know how to block form submitting from websites that are not on my domain?

I changed my form a few times, but he can find the input names just as simply as I changed them.

Comment: Can we see your code that accepts this input? Do this by editing the question, and don't forget to tag it with the language you are using.

Answer (score 5):

The only fail-safe way to prevent a submission of a form with undesirable values is to perform validation on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the referrer (`Request.ServerVariables("http_referrer")`) should tell you the page the request came from. As Oleg said you should additionally validate the returned form data in any case.

Comment: i will try damn it sucks that it cant be blocked

Comment: Checking the referrer will also block submissions that use the right page but have the browser set not to send Referer headers, for one reason or another. So it’s a wrong way, if the intent is just to make sure that the input data values are acceptable (e.g., age and country have been taken from some specific sets of values).